# flex4: fx|XML - how to do complex search

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex4

i would like to search inside an fx|XML Object for a node with `label='notifications'`
and inside of it a node with `label='notifications2'` and i want to get an XML contains what's in it.

this is my Flex 4 Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="_ccInit()">

<!-- Launch your application by right clicking within this class and select Debug As > FDT SWF Application -->

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="moshe">
        <node state="root_item" label="notifications">
        <node state="root_item" label="notifications2">
                <node state="item" label="item" a="test1" b="test2" />
        </node>
            <node state="root_item" label="Winnings" />
            <node state="root_item" label="Winnings2" />
            <node state="root_item" label="Winnings3" />
            <node state="root_item" label="Winnings4" />
            <node state="root_item" label="Winnings5" />
        </node>
    </fx:XML>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        private function _ccInit():void {
            var newXml:XML = moshe.(@label == "notifications").(@label == "notifications2") as XML;
            Alert.show(newXml.toString());          
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

newXml is null. how can i resolve the issue ?

thanks

Comment: i already tried several search methods, i pasted this one to sum what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search will never work. You dont define a rootTag for the moshe XML, and you cannot have *root tag*, '*nodes*' and '*elements*' with the same name i.e. node. You will have to have properly formatted XML.

A search for *Flex XML Search* on StackOverflow will give plenty of examples

Comment: His xml seems correct. Problem is in the search: var newXml:XML = moshe. **node** .(@label == "notifications"). **node** .(@label == "notifications2") **[0]**;

Comment: First node is the root, it's just tabs aren't right. He would get compile error otherwise.

Comment: why can't I have a root tag with the same name? In TourDeFlex in E4X example they use root tag named item as well the child nodes with the same name.

Comment: i checked on google and other stackoverflow answer, I come up with  moshe.children().(@label == "notifications2"). the root node is always the same so I can use children(). it returns the proper xml element that i required. i did not need to change the xml list at all. thanks

Comment: That leaves out the label='notifications' part of the question